# Error when saving from format(val(textbox.text), "#,##0") to numeric field type in SQL

Tags: vb.net

In SQL Server, I have a table like this:

**tableItem**
**------------------------**
**item**   | varchar (15),
**price**  | numeric(18, 2)

**In VB.NET, I have the code:**

```
textbox1.text = "Book"  
textbox2.text = 20.000,00
textbox2.text  = format(val(textbox2.text), "#,##0.00")
```

**Procedure Save :**

```
dim sqlQuery as string = "insert into tableItem(item,price) values('" & textbox1.Text & "','" & textbox2.Text & "')"     
Try
        conn.open()
        With Cmd
            .Connection = Conn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = sqlQuery
            .ExecuteNonQuery
        End With

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error at : " & ex.Message)
Finally
    conn.close()
End Try
```

but I am getting the error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

If I change `& textbox2.Text &` to `& val(textbox2.text)  &` in the query, the data is stored only **20** in **price**.

Comment: For better read- and searchability please include the error message as text and not as an image.

Comment: What is the type of column price?

Comment: the type of column price in table is numeric (i'm sorry about my description above) there is not number but numeric(18, 0)

Comment: Ah sorry you post it in the question. Maybe you have to specify the digits right of the decimal point.

Comment: If i add val(textbox2.text) in the query, the data is stored only 20

Comment: Try change it to numeric(18, 3)

Comment: i have try, but it still error
note : 20.000 (twenty thousand)

Comment: thanks for your attentions @PaulKertscher,,, 
the error message is "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

Comment: @AgusTri - please edit the question accordingly and do not add the details as a comment

Comment: Data is stored only 20 because your column type is numeric(18,0). This mean you have zero digits after dot. If you change it to numeric(18,3) you can store 3 digits after dot. Any other characters after this 3 digits will be ignored.

Comment: I've changed my question... please help and thanks you

Comment: Why not store it like 20000.00 numeric and when you need it use - SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST('20000.00' AS money), 1)

Comment: @BorisSerafimov - because i want to display in textbox with thousand sparator. and I only know that way, like - textbox2.text  = format(val(textbox2.text), "#,##0.00"). If I do not use that way, there's no problem

Answer (score 0):

you are not allowed to assign 20.000,00 to a textbox2.Text property.
Try:

```
textbox2.text = "20.00"
```

On another note I would not pass the variables directly into the SQL insert query. Try the code below:

```
dim sqlQuery as string = "insert into tableItem(item,price) values(@item, @price)"     
Try
    conn.open()
    With Cmd
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@item, textbox1.text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@price, textbox2.text)
        .Connection = Conn
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = sqlQuery
        .ExecuteNonQuery
    End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error at : " & ex.Message)
End Try
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, but I found another way to keep using
`format(val(texbox2.text), "#,##0")`
on the keypress

and return to its original value (integer) using
`Format(texbox2.text, "General Number")`

I found this answer from other similar people's questions.
Thanks very much.